# Virtualizedlists should never be nested inside plain scrollviews in latest react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

In the latest `react-native` CLI facing issue virtualizedlists should never be nested inside plain scrollviews in `Flatlist` inside `Scrollview` this screen UI working fine in the past versions below is my `react-native info`

```
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
react-native: 0.65.1 => 0.65.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as explained by the error, you have to refactor your code!

Like:

```
<ScrollView>
  ...
  <FlatList /> // here a list embedded in another list of components
  ...
</ScrollView>
```

is not longer allowed

Comment: I followed the same but issue in the latest react-native if this is not allowed then any other solution for flatlist inside scrollview